# Change order in legend in lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I wonder if there is anyway to change the order of series in a legend in lattice?
For example if I have a plot of overlaid densities a,b, and c but in the legend I want the order to be c,b,a is there anyway I can do that?

```
dat <- data.frame(dens = c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 10, 5), rnorm(100,-10,5))
              , lines = rep(c("a", "b","c"), each = 100))

densityplot(~dens,data=dat,groups = lines,
        plot.points = FALSE, ref = TRUE, 
        auto.key = list(corner=c(1,0.95)))
```

Density Plot Figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following where you set the levels of `lines` as ordered in reverse order:

```
library(lattice)

lev <- c('c','b','a')
dat <- data.frame(dens  = c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 10, 5), rnorm(100,-10,5)),
                  lines = factor(rep(c("a", "b","c"), each = 100),
                                levels=lev, labels=lev, ordered = TRUE))

densityplot(~dens,data=dat,groups = lines,
        plot.points = FALSE, ref = TRUE, 
        auto.key = list(corner=c(1,0.95)))
```

Here is the result.

[image]